# Colloquial alternatives to questions regarding the ordinals

Tags: phrase-requests, questions, colloquialisms, ordinal-numbers

I'm very well aware that this question is asked a myriad of times before but I want to know how one would phrase a question in every-day language to get the answer *"n-th"*.

- What ordinal number reflects the position of you
  in the set of candidates?
- Where do you fall in order among all candidates?
- In the sequence of candidates, what is the position of yours?

These were suggested in the previous questions but they all sound very formal. Could one say *"What place did you take in the exam?"* Are there any other alternatives? How does *"how manyth"* sound to a native speaker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"What was your ranking in your class?"***

for additional clarification, you can also phrase it like this:

***"What was your ranking in your class? (Ex. 1st, 2nd, 45th, etc.)"***

Comment: Or "where do you rank..."

Comment: In the context of a contest, I would add "How did you place (in the contest)?"